# Why is the equality $|L\backslash M_H|=|L|-|M_H|$true? Why $|L\backslash M_H|\ge|U|$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

[image]

**Doubt on underline 1** What do you mean by the edge subgraph of $G$ defined by $L$?IsIt a subgraph with all edges from $L$?

**Doubt on underline 2** Why is the equality $|L \backslash M_H|=|L|-|M_H|$true? Why $|L\backslash M_H|\ge|U|$? Can you please explain?

Comment: Please don't just post a photo, please type out the important parts, and possibly link to the full document if it is particularly long. Typing it out means that your question is searchable in the future

Comment: @lioness99a I got how the equality is coming. number of edge[H]=$|L|$.Isn't follow directly from the fact that $M_H\subset L$?

Comment: @Mathgeek yes, I think your argument is true. Since $H$ is a spanning subgraph of $G$ and $L$ is an edge covering of $G$, therefore a matching of $H$, consisting of the independent edges of $H$, a spanning subgraph of $G$, which could be covered by $L$, must necessarily be a subset of $L$

Comment: @Mathgeek for edge subgraph, look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Edge-InducedSubgraph.html)